# How to disable zoom product image when click in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, zoom

How to disable zoom product image when click in Magento 2.
I want disable zoom function.
I tryed change this code in `view.xml` but it not working.

My code change:

```
<var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
        <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
        <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
        <var name="thumbmargin">20</var>
        <var name="thumbborderwidth">1</var>
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
        </var>
        <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview in fullscreen (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title in fullscreen(true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in fullscreen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
            <var name="navarrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>

    <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    </var>
```

Please help me fix it, thanks all.

Comment: You might get a cache issue, try to check after clear your cache.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You must check regarding proper theme files. your view.xml file must be inside your current theme and once you change setting you need to flush the cache. if still not working than let me know

Thank you